# Service and view

Tags: android

Can i get a view by calling findIdBy(R.id.x) in a Service?
thanks

Comment: This is plain wrong! For what purpose you need view in a service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Should you attempt it: No.

Is it good practice: No.

Would it ever be useful to do this: No.

If you want to do this are you doing something wrong: Yes

Is it possible, in a convoluted way that goes against everything that you should do in an Android idiomatic program: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate views defined in an XML file using

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(...)
```

See the `SoftKeyboard` example for why and how to do this in a service context